# How to edit system sound in Audacity?

Tags: windows, audio, audacity, system-sounds, sound-editing

I can apply certain effects to audio files in Audacity. Can I apply them to the entire Windows system as well?

Like the sound coming from my speakers. I don't want to *record* it, but *edit* it in Audacity and have that change saved and made globally in Windows itself.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds (pun intended) as though you want to apply a set of chosen sound effects to whatever sounds are being played by your system.

This is not possible with Audacity. Audacity is a "WAV editor", an editor of sound files. It cannot patch into your audio playback path and modify the sounds being played in real time. Many of its effects take longer than real time to run, so they would not be useful for this purpose anyway.

There are sound cards that have built-in DSP effects processors that are normally "in the path" for sound playback, with control panels that let you choose what effects you want.

Comment: Is there an Audacity plugin for this, then? Or another app to do it?

Comment: You could look into VSTHost and its plugins - all free. VST plugins are little programs that provide various audio filtering functions (and they are usable within Audacity, too). VSTHost lets you use them to process real-time audio. See http://nerds-central.blogspot.com/2011/01/vsthost-as-ultra-powerful-real-time.html (no connection to that site or to anything it talks about)

Comment: Can I export audacity effects as vst?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: However I'd think you'd be able to find just about anything you'd want as VST plugins.